# Levi-Civita and Kronecker Delta

Tags: tensor-calculus

To prove this,
$$
\sum_{pq}
\epsilon_{ipq}
\epsilon_{jpq}
= 2\delta_{ij}
$$

I used Levi-Civita and delta relation

$$
\sum_{q}
\epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{jpq} = \delta_{ij}\delta_{pp}-\delta_{ip}\delta_{pj}
$$
then first and second term both will be just $\delta_{ij}$ so both cancel out.

Where it is going wrong? Since using that relation I am getting zero not as twice of delta.

Answer (score 4):

If the indices run from $1$ to $3$ then $$\sum_p\delta_{pp}=3$$ which gives the desired result.

Comment: thanks!! missed the p summation part